# Cross Browser Full Width CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been given a challenge of recreating a certain website but I am unsure what the best way is to create a full width cross browser template.  I would be using HTML 5 and so far I have:

Do I just use 100% as width?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Logo Position</h1>
        </header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    width:990px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:#000;
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    color:#184C82;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should also use like that..

```css
#wrapper {
 width:100%; /* or width:990px; */
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: why you give position:absolute ?

Comment: It's a wrong way to create your whole layout in absolute position.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work - absolute positioning and setting width and height do nothing to neutralize the margin/padding that browsers insert on the html/body element.  Basically, all this answer does is cause a horizontal scrollbar by forcing the strict width behavior instead of the nicer block element behavior (tested in Chrome).  Absolute positioning and setting the left, right and top properties to 0 could conceivably work, but that's not what you did here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can just ignore the width (that is, not set it anywhere, or set it to `auto` if it was previously set by something you don't control), and it will default to full width... with a small margin around the edges.  If you want that margin gone (cross-browser), you need to set both margin and padding to 0 on both `body` and `html`:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Messing with the height is generally only needed if you want to push a footer down to the bottom of the screen when the page content is short.  You didn't ask for that, so I won't elaborate.  (There are existing Stack Overflow questions on that topic anyway.)

Certain elements - particularly tables - do need a `width: 100%` declaration, but divs and the body do not, unless you've used one of the various CSS declarations that cause shrinkwrapping (i.e. `display: inline-block`, `float: left` or `position: absolute`).  Note that `width: 100%` is not exactly the same as the default behavior of block elements (including the body) - block elements take up as much room as is available, respecting their margins, border and padding, whereas anything with `width: 100%` will be just as wide as its parent element - and any margin, border or padding will stick out beyond that.

Comment: @Brian You are spot on.

once the body and html tag has set like so
`body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Then the header, sidebar footer etc can conveniently use % such as 100%, 30%

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `<header>` width to `100%` will only make it the width of its parent, which is `990px`. If you wish to make it extend to 100% the viewport width, you will need to either take it out of the wrapper, position it with `absolute` or `fixed`, or use `:before` and/or `:after` to give the impression of it being the width of the viewport.

Chris Coyier demonstrated this last method in his article *[Full Browser Width Bars](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `width:100%` on the header, and then remove the wrapper. Build the separate parts of your layout as separate DIVs, using `<body>` as your parent element. You'll be golden!