# Site Header Browser Width

Tags: css, header

I want to make site header to appear full browser width.

I have tried adding

```
    .site-header {
        position: relative;
        padding: 24px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

Kindly support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Browser Full Width CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779318/cross-browser-full-width-css)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve because your question it's not very clear, but perhaps you want to try resetting the default margin/padding for body?

```
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;    
    }
```